AWS Cors Issue For S3 + Application Load Balancer
My spring boot webservice is running in a container on a ec2 container.
I set up an Application Load Balancer in front of this ec2 container. Any request coming from ALB 443 port is redirected to ec2's 8080 port for my microservice.
On the other hand, I have my angular web app is served on an s3 bucket and I added both the s3 bucket and the ALB behind a cloudfront distribution. Now my issue is that when i call a webservice from my angular app I get the following error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dz9tc8yjwihu0.cloudfront.net/api/signuptoemaillist' from origin 'https://www.dailyenglishacademy.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here I will share my cloudfront s3 behaviour and ALB settings to show i actually added the required things.
Kotlin Code for backend
class CorsConfig {
@Bean
fun corsFilter(): CorsFilter {
    val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
    val config = CorsConfiguration()

    // Allow credentials if required
    config.allowCredentials = true

    // Add allowed origins (CloudFront and your domain)
    config.addAllowedOrigin("https://dz9tc8yjwihu0.cloudfront.net") // CloudFront URL
    config.addAllowedOrigin("https://www.dailyenglishacademy.com") // Your domain

    // Allow all headers
    config.addAllowedHeader("*")

    // Allow all HTTP methods (GET, POST, OPTIONS, etc.)
    config.addAllowedMethod("*")

    // Expose these headers to the browser, if needed (this is useful for preflight)
    config.addExposedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
    config.addExposedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")

    // Register the configuration for all endpoints
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config)

    return CorsFilter(source)
}

}





